# Codeigniter's Session Library: How to get the correct IP Address when using Proxy

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, cloudflare

I have an application that uses Codeigniter 3x and Cloudflare for adding an extra security layer.

When I use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` my application returns Cloudflare's IP and not my user's IP, so I always need to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']` instead.

So far, ok. When I need my user's IP in any controller I reach out to `$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']`. The problem is that my Session Library doesn't do that. **And my ci_sessions table is filled with Cloudflare's IPs.**

So my question may be a little broad, but I needed some ideas on how to fix that without messing with CI's core files? I've noticed that there's a file on `system/libraries/session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php` that is using the remote address. How can I extend it?

Cheers!

Comment: Are you actually using `sess_match_ip = true` in your session config? You might find [this post](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-66143.html) interesting. Read about creating custom drivers for the sesion class [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#custom-drivers)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @DFriend. Using this link I was able to create a custom driver to override it. I'll post the solution here.

Comment: You're not supposed to do this.

Comment: Hi @Narf. Thank you for commenting. But why? Should I leave all my ci_sessions IP addresses with Cloudflare's IP's? I'm not actually using them for anything (not sure about CI's core, though), just thought it would be better to store real user's values.

Comment: It only matters if you use `sess_match_ip`, and that's not sustainable outside of intranet environments, because public IP addresses can change often. In other words: yes, leave it with CF's addresses.

Comment: Thanks @Narf. Just posted this as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as @Narf commented, ci_sessions ip_address only matters if you use sess_match_ip (that's a setting in config.php). And, in his own words:

> that's not sustainable outside of intranet environments, because public IP addresses can change often

So his recommendation is to leave ci_sessions table with Cloudfare's addresses. I thought it would be good to leave this here for future reference.

But if you really need to create custom drivers, @DFriend's recommendation works like a charm. You can find more information about this on CI's user guide, [in this section](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#custom-drivers).

And if you want to get your user's IP for another purpose, just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']` or even `$this->server('HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP')`. It works for me.

I really want to thank you guys for helping me figure this out.

Cheers!